# How to update the user location with Geolocator if the app is in the Foreground?

Tags: flutter

The app should update the rider's location every second whatever the app is alive or in the foreground, I tried to install the Geolocator and it succeed but whenever the app is in that background or in the Foreground it stops responding.How to solve with that issue.

Some recommend me to work with workmanager !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Push the latitude and longitude of the device from within the background service using [background_locater](https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator) plugin

Comment: i want to update the rider's location every second until he reaches the location, does this packages helps me with that even if the app is closed?

Comment: Yes, this package will work even after the app is closed completely

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can i make timer with this package i mean every second update the user location, because i didn't find in the docs place to put the timer with it.

Comment: Yes you can update user location in every second by setting the interval in the service

Answer (score 2):

To push location in foreground through foreground service and even when device reboots you can use following library

https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator